# Function should be returning a promise of a string but doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to upload an image and return it's id with the following code:

```
export function uploadImage(file: any, location: string, next: any): Promise<string> {
    try {
        if (!file) {
            throw new Error("No Image file");
        }
        const id = location + "/" + utilities.generatePushID();
        const options = {
            resource_type: "raw",
            public_id: id,
        };
        return cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(options, (error: any, result: any) => {
            if (error) {
                 throw new Error("Couldn't upload");
             }
             return result.public_id;
        }).end(file.buffer);
    } catch (err) {
         return next(InternalError(err));
    }
}
```

However, whenever I try to call the function, it gives me back an `UploadStream` object rather than the `string` that I want. It's as if it immediately returns the uploader, rather than the result of the uploader. Why?

Comment: The `.upload_stream` call looks callback-based, not Promise-based..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `upload_stream` doesn't return an Promise, if you want to make is promisify, try this one:

```js
export async function uploadImage(file: any, location: string, next: any): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            if (!file) {
                reject(new Error("No Image file"));
            }
            const id = location + "/" + utilities.generatePushID();
            const options = {
                resource_type: "raw",
                public_id: id,
            };
            return cloudinary.uploader.upload_stream(options, (error: any, result: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    reject(new Error("Couldn't upload"));
                }
                result(result.public_id);
            }).end(file.buffer);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(InternalError(err));
        } 
    });
}
```

and get rid of `next` because it looks like it's a callback, then you will be able to call it like:

```js
const public_id = await uploadImage(...);
// or
uploadImage(...).then(public_id => console.log(public_id)).catch(() => console.error);
```

Regards.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like it, gives me the error: `[ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: Fixed the error by changing `Promise` to `Promise<string>`, and it works :)

Comment: Just a side note - if you're returning a promise you don't need it to be an async function.   It can just be a regular function that returns a promise and that will still be awaitable.